# Error installing Jabber server on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, jabber

I am having some issues trying to setup a Jabber server on Ubuntu 10.04

```
root@li240-199:/home/ioudas/jabberd14-1.6.1.1# apt-get install jabber
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
jabber is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 81 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up jabberd14 (1.6.1.1-5) ...
chown: cannot access `/etc/jabber/jabber.xml': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing jabberd14 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jabber:
 jabber depends on jabberd14; however:
  Package jabberd14 is not configured yet.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: error processing jabber (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jabberd14
 jabber
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear you have configured apt-get not to ask for configuration data.
Try running `sudo dpkg --configure jabberd14` to configure jabberd14.

Alternatively, you could try `dpkg-reconfigure jabberd14` to do the configuration.

Try running `dpkg-reconfigure debconf` to see if you have set the interface to noninteractive which will turn of prompts for required configuration data when installing new packages.

Comment: root@li240-199:/home/ioudas# dpkg-reconfigure jabberd14
 * Stopping Jabber/XMPP server jabberd14                                 [ OK ]
 * Starting Jabber/XMPP server jabberd14                                        Configuration parsing using /etc/jabber/jabber.xml failed: syntax error at line 1 and column 0


root@li240-199:/home/ioudas# dpkg --configure jabberd14
dpkg: error processing jabberd14 (--configure):
 package jabberd14 is already installed and configured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jabberd14


Appears to be set to interactive

Comment: It looks like the jabber.xml file is corrupt or empty.  Try editing it.  Check /usr/share/doc/jabberd14 for configuration information, and possibly a sample configuration.  dpkg-reconfigure might correct the configuration file.

Comment: Manged to copy the default jabber xml conf back and get the service up.. When connecting i now get. 1 account was disabled because you signed on from another location:

Comment: Update /etc/default/jabberd to have your hostname.  Stop and start jabberd

Comment: Check the documentation at http://jabberd.org for the installation guide and configuration hints.  You will need to edit jabber.xml for it to be useful.

Comment: Setting jabber to use local host or a host i define gives me the same error message. I have read the ubuntu and jabberd.org install guide.

Comment: It you log on to a user id for a second time, the first gets logged out.  Use two ids for testing.  The jabber2 package seems to have more up to date and complete documentation.

Comment: Yeah I for the life of me cant get any id's going.

Comment: Try unininstalling with the purge option, then reinstalling.  I didn't have any problem getting things going using the old setup instructions.  User ids end up in a subdirectory in the spool directory.  It appears the same user id can be used if the resource changes.  I followed the checkpoint instruction in http://jabberd.org/1.4/doc/adminguide

Comment: Yeah ive tried this on now two different boxes with the same issue. I dont think the setup instructions work. Typical.

Comment: Which step fails?

Comment: No steps fail the above error is listed when connecting.

Comment: I noticed you have a lot of unpatched packages.  Run apt-get safe-upgrade and see if the install problem is fixed.